# How to get the xml node value in string

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I tried the below code to get the value of a particular node, but while loading the xml this exception is thrown:

**Exception:**

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <Date>11-07-2013</Date> 
    <Start_Time>PM 01:37:11</Start_Time> 
    <End_Time>PM 01:37:14</End_Time> 
    <Total_Time>00:00:03</Total_Time> 
    <Interval_Time/>
    <Worked_Time>00:00:03</Worked_Time> 
    <Short_Fall>08:29:57</Short_Fall> 
    <Gain_Time>00:00:00</Gain_Time> 
</Data>
```

**C#:**

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
filePath = @"D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml";
xml.LoadXml(filePath);  // Exception occurs here 
XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Data[@*]/Short_Fall");
string id = node["Short_Fall"].InnerText;
```

**Modified Code**

**C#:**

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
filePath = @"D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml";
xml.Load(filePath);  
XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Data[@*]/Short_Fall");
string id = node["Short_Fall"].InnerText; // Exception occurs here ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data at the root level is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748668/data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid)

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ to XML? It's much easier and more dev-friendly then old `XmlDocument` class.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem in your code is `xml.LoadXml(filePath);`

> `LoadXml` method take parameter as **xml data** not the **xml file path**

Try this code

```
   string xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml");
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
                XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Short_Fall");
                string Short_Fall=string.Empty;
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    Short_Fall = node.InnerText;
                }
```

**Edit**

Seeing the last edit of your question i found the solution,

Just replace the below 2 lines

```
XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Data[@*]/Short_Fall");
string id = node["Short_Fall"].InnerText; // Exception occurs here ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.")
```

with

```
string id = xml.SelectSingleNode("Data/Short_Fall").InnerText;
```

It should solve your problem or you can use the solution i provided earlier.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `.Load` and not `.LoadXML`

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx)

"The LoadXml method is for loading an XML string directly. You want to use the Load method instead."

ref : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544475/data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1-why-i-get-this-error-whil)

Comment: I used Load method now exception isn't thrown but   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   is thrown at the line    string id = node["Short_Fall"].InnerText;

Comment: I think it is because you are already at Short_Fall 
as you did in your previous line 

xml.SelectSingleNode("/Data[@*]/Short_Fall");

Comment: so how to get that particular node value

Comment: try node.InnerText directly

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.Load(@"D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml");
XmlNodeList n = d.GetElementsByTagName("Short_Fall");
if(n != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(n[0].InnerText); //Will output '08:29:57'
}

or you could wrap in foreach loop to print each value

XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.Load(@"D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml");
XmlNodeList n = d.GetElementsByTagName("Short_Fall");
if(n != null) {
    foreach(XmlNode curr in n) {
        Console.WriteLine(curr.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These posts helped me get past a couple of issues I had creating a CLR Stored Procedure with Restful API call against Infor M3 API.

The XML Result from these API's look like this for my code below:

```
miResult xmlns="http://lawson.com/m3/miaccess">
    <Program>MMS200MI</Program>
    <Transaction>Get</Transaction>
    <Metadata>...</Metadata>
    <MIRecord>
        <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
        <NameValue>
            <Name>STAT</Name>
            <Value>20</Value>
        </NameValue>
        <NameValue>
            <Name>ITNO</Name>
            <Value>ITEM123</Value>
        </NameValue>
        <NameValue>
            <Name>ITDS</Name>
            <Value>ITEM DESCRIPTION 123 </Value>
        </NameValue>
...
```

The CLR C# Code to accomplish listing out the Resultset from the API works as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void CallM3API_Test1()
    {
        SqlPipe pipe_msg = SqlContext.Pipe;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://M3Server.domain.com:12345/m3api-rest/execute/MMS200MI/Get?ITNO=ITEM123");

            request.Method = "Get";
            request.ContentLength = 0;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserID@domain.com", "MyPassword");
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Accept = "application/xml";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                    using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            string strContent = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                            xdoc.LoadXml(strContent);
                            try
                            {
                                SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;

                                //Define Output Columns and Max Length of each Column in the Resultset    
                                SqlMetaData[] cols = new SqlMetaData[2];
                                cols[0] = new SqlMetaData("Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                                cols[1] = new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 120);
                                SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(cols);

                                pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

                                XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("NameValue");
                                //List ALL Output Names + Values
                                foreach (XmlNode nodeRes in nodeList)
                                {
                                    record.SetSqlString(0, nodeRes["Name"].InnerText);
                                    record.SetSqlString(1, nodeRes["Value"].InnerText);

                                    pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
                                }

                                pipe.SendResultsEnd();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Error (readStream): " + ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Error (CallM3API_Test1): " + ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this provides helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and below code solved.

-> If you have xml file path

**C#**

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string filePath = @"D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml";
xml.Load(filePath);
string shortFall = xmlDc.SelectSingleNode("Data/Short_Fall").InnerText;
```

-> If you have xml string, then below code works

**C#**

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlString= "your xml string";
xml.LoadXML(xmlString);
string shortFall = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Data/Short_Fall").InnerText;
```