# How to get node values in XML file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, in this XML you can see the RESPONSE_DATA tag. This tag have some more inner tags. I need to get all the values inside PERSON_DATA tags. Also i need to get all the other value in below xml file.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n
<HUMAN_VERIFICATION xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RESPONSE_DATA>
      <RESPONSE_STATUS>
         <ERROR>100</ERROR>
         <MESSAGE>successful</MESSAGE>
      </RESPONSE_STATUS>
      <CONTACT_NUMBER>3120202456011</CONTACT_NUMBER>
      <PERSON_DATA>
         <NAME>Alex</NAME>
         <DATE_OF_BIRTH>10-9-1982</DATE_OF_BIRTH>
         <BIRTH_PLACE>Washington</BIRTH_PLACE>
         <EXPIRY>2020-12-15</EXPIRY>
      </PERSON_DATA>
      <CARD_TYPE>idcard</CARD_TYPE>
   </RESPONSE_DATA>
</HUMAN_VERIFICATION>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you asking for a tutorial on XML handling with C# ?

Comment: please reformat your XML...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590182/how-to-get-the-xml-node-value-in-string Hope it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code it may be helpful for you.

```
XmlDocument newdoc = new XmlDocument();
newdoc.InnerXml = " <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><HUMAN_VERIFICATION><RESPONSE_DATA><RESPONSE_STATUS><ERR>100</ERROR><MESSAGE>successful</MESSAGE></RESPONSE_STATUS><CONTACT_NUMBER>3120202456011</ CONTACT _NUMBER><PERSON_DATA><NAME>Alex</NAME><DATE_OF_BIRTH>10-9-1982</DATE_OF_BIRTH><BIRTH_PLACE>Washington</BIRTH_PLACE><EXPIRY>2020-12-15</EXPIRY></PERSON_DATA><CARD_TYPE>idcard</CARD_TYPE></RESPONSE_DATA></HUMAN_VERIFICATION>";

var selectnode = "HUMAN_VERIFICATION/RESPONSE_DATA/PERSON_DATA";
var nodes = newdoc.SelectNodes(selectnode);
foreach (XmlNode nod in nodes)
{
    string name   = nod["NAME"         ].InnerText;
    string dob    = nod["DATE_OF_BIRTH"].InnerText;
    string place  = nod["BIRTH_PLACE"  ].InnerText;
    string expiry = nod["EXPIRY"       ].InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine("Person: {0} {1} {2} {3}", name, dob, place, expiry);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `Linq` to `Xml`.

```
var results = doc.Descendants("PERSON_DATA")      // Flatten the hierarchy and look for PERSON_DATA                
    .Select(x=> new 
            {
                NAME = (string)x.Element("NAME"),
                DATE_OF_BIRTH = (string)x.Element("DATE_OF_BIRTH"),
                BIRTH_PLACE = (string)x.Element("BIRTH_PLACE"),
                EXPIRY = (string)x.Element("EXPIRY"),
            });
```

Check the [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qHCsSO)

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy and intuitive with System.Xml.Linq.

```
var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<HUMAN_VERIFICATION xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n  <RESPONSE_DATA>\r\n    <RESPONSE_STATUS>\r\n      <ERROR>100</ERROR>\r\n      <MESSAGE>successful</MESSAGE>\r\n    </RESPONSE_STATUS>\r\n    <CONTACT_NUMBER>3120202456011</CONTACT_NUMBER>\r\n    <PERSON_DATA>\r\n      <NAME>Alex</NAME>\r\n     <DATE_OF_BIRTH>10-9-1982</DATE_OF_BIRTH>\r\n      <BIRTH_PLACE>Washington</BIRTH_PLACE>\r\n      <EXPIRY>2020-12-15</EXPIRY>\r\n    </PERSON_DATA>\r\n    <CARD_TYPE>idcard</CARD_TYPE>\r\n  </RESPONSE_DATA>\r\n</HUMAN_VERIFICATION>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var name = document.Element("HUMAN_VERIFICATION").Element("RESPONSE_DATA").Element("PERSON_DATA").Element("NAME").Value;
```

OR

```
var personData = document.Element("HUMAN_VERIFICATION").Element("RESPONSE_DATA").Element("PERSON_DATA").Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.ToString(), e => e.Value);
```