# C# Read Xml config file

Tags: c#, xml, io, config

I have a Xml config file with `true` and `false` statements in it. I need a `function` which will return the `bool` value.

```
<Configs>
     <steerWithMouse>true</steerWithMouse>
     <debug>false</debug>
</Configs>
```

The function would need a `string` value for the node to go after. So something like this:

`bool steerWithMouse = ReadConfigs("SteerWithMouse");`

`bool debug = ReadConfigs("debug");`

```
public bool ReadConfigs(string config) {

        try {
            //Where the code should go.

        }
        catch {
            //If the program fails to find or load the file correctly.

            ModConsole.Error("Falied to load configs file."); //The console.
            steerWithMouse = true;
            debug = false;
        }
    }
```

Due to my inexperience in Xml files I have only meet frustration when trying to do this. It either didn't say anything, didn't compile or returned the whole document. I would gladly accept some help with this.

Comment: What research did you do about how to read xml file and parse its data? Did you find anything useful? Did you apply that and try to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have been searching all day (yesterday) for a bunch of solutions. But none of those helped me. I erased it because of how messy my code where with commented out snippets and half made lines.

Comment: Have you considered letting [AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) handle the reading part and just [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) the string value?

Comment: Can you share whatever solution you tried and tell us what issue you are facing with that ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4aXKPN0nK0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DwANN5_BoE
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c
http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm

Just a few I read.

Comment: What I want is a function that reads a Xml file and returns the node that matches the search string as a bool.
And if it fails to either find the file in question or doesn't find the matching node, it will print a error message and set the variables to the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool ReadConfigs(string config) {

        string statement = null;

        try {
            string xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(ModLoader.GetModConfigFolder(this) + "\\configs.xml");
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(config);
            string Short_Fall = string.Empty;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) {
                statement = node.InnerText;

            }
        }
        catch {
            ModConsole.Error("Falied to load configs file!");
            statement = null;
        }

        try {

            if (statement != null) {
                return bool.Parse(statement);
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch {
            ModConsole.Error("Invalid syntax in configs!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590182/how-to-get-the-xml-node-value-in-string) copy paste seems to have solved it.