# retrieving data from xml file and posting it to listbox

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xmldocument

I'm trying to load data from the nodes in my xml file to get them to post in a listbox. 
Here is what my xml file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MovieData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
  </Movie>
</MovieData>
```

Here is what i am trying to do.

```
try
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(movieListXML);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/MovieData[@*]");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
        {
            XmlNode movie = xn.SelectSingleNode("Movie");
            if (movie != null)
            {
                movieTypeListBox.Items.Add(movie["Name"].InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Updated code still has problem. It only shows one movie name instead of all of the movie names.

```
try
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(movieListXML);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/MovieData");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
        {
            XmlNode movie = xn.SelectSingleNode("Movie");
            if (movie != null)
            {
                movieTypeListBox.Items.Add(movie["Name"].InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where my problem is ?

Another question: Can someone show me how to organize the data alphabetically by the name of the Movie ?

Comment: what line(of your code) do you get the error at  is it at the `doc.loadXML` method?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that it is trying to read this data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> but failing since it has the ? at the start. My advice would be to use a DataGrid instead, then get the data from that as you want to :)

Comment: by the way, where is `movieListXML` defined?

Comment: It is defined at the start. In the initialize method. It is the path of the xml file. It is correct since it lets me add stuff and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data at the root level is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748668/data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid). You are using `LoadXml` when you should be using `Load`.

Comment: Yup that has been mentioned and fixed so far. I have a new problem look above at updated code and problem.

Comment: @user2860193 if you have a new problem, than please post a new question, and only do so if you can't figure it out on your own.  We don't need more [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @user2860193 by the way, you've already used `SelectSingleNode`, `SelectNodes`, and a `foreach` loop in your code sample.  you just have to use `SelectNodes` to get your `Movie`s and use `SelectSingleNode` to get your `MovieData` instead of the other way around.

Comment: BTW, you really should start using LINQ to XML. It's a lot easier for the kinds of things you need to do, like sorting the XML.

Comment: I've had no problem with the way I do it now but I will look into LINQ to XML when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that `movieListXML` might be a filename in which case you want to call

```
//movieListXML = @"c:\xmlFile.xml";
doc.Load(movieListXML);
```

instead of

```
//movieListXML = @"<MovieData><Movie></Movie></MovieData>";
doc.LoadXml(movieListXML);
```

which takes the actual XML in as a string

Comment: I changed what suggested. Now i don't get the error but it still doesn't show the data into the list box.

Comment: @user2860193 change `doc.SelectNodes("/MovieData[@*]");` to `doc.SelectNodes("/MovieData");`

Comment: That partially worked. I changed the things suggested and it shows only the first movie name in the list box. I want it to show all of them. Thanks for your help. Hopefully you can help me solve this.

Comment: @user2860193 yes, that's what you'd expect.  have a second look at your code,  you're selecting a list of `MovieData`(which there is only one of), and you're only selecting a single instance of `Movie` from each one

Comment: @user2860193 I think that you can figure out the rest from here, If you don't understand how to do it, than you can make another question

Comment: I'm really new to this lol. Just learned C# about 2 days ago. Can you show me the correct way to do it please ?

Answer (score 1):

check your xml file - it's likely got a Bite order marker in it.  open the file in a hex editor and delete the non printing characters from the start of the file.

As your xml looks fine - particularly the xml declaration - I'm pretty sure this will be your problem.

depending on the character encoding used when the file was created it'll be somehting like : 0xFEFF (if its utf-8 - think that ones little endian)

Here's how to get all the movie names out :

```
           XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/MovieData/Movie");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(xn["Name"].InnerText);
            }
```

if you want to sort them too then its probably easier to XDocument.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean i posted the whole xml file in the above post. I'm using visual studio to look at the file. How do i do it in that ?  I'm very new to this only been doing it about 2 days now.
Thanks for your help

Comment: yup thats what I thought when i first encountered this problem - the file looks fine.  But, honestly, look at the file in a hex editor - I bet there are 2 or 3 non printable characters at the start of it.

Comment: in vs right click the xml file in your project and click open with ....  Then select binary editior. In fact I've just done exactly that for any random xml file i have - and the file starts with 0xEFBBBF - can;t remember which unicode encoding thats for.  While editing an xml file - just adding the encoding='' attribute can set this value again inside of vs

Comment: I looked at it through the binary editor like you said. This is what it shows EF BB BF is that what i delete ? I deleted that and still nothing.

Comment: Yup - thats what you need to delete.  You didn't reopen the file in vs text editor did you - It'll write the BOM back if you do.

Comment: It showed the same error. But i did what suggested below by changing doc.LoadXml to doc.Load and i get no error but nothing is shown in the list box

Comment: the doc.load is the correct method if the parameter is a filename. if its not getting the error then the xml file has loaded.  does your for loop iterate through any data -or just skip straight past.

Comment: It now shows only one movie name in the list box. Updated code is above.

Comment: oops - I'd assumed you were loading the xml as a string - so i guess you can ignore the bom stuff.  updated answer to get you all the movie names