# using c# ignore a line with doctype from xml

Tags: c#, xml, excel, console

i have developed a project in using c#, reads xml file and redirects the specified output in CSV file.

i am getting error in my code as from                     `XDoc.LoadXml(filenamestr)` it goes directly to catch block skipping the in between commands.

```
try
{
     XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
     XDoc.LoadXml(filenamestr);
     XmlDocumentType XDType = XDoc.DocumentType;
     XDoc.RemoveChild(XDType);
     XDoc.Save(filenamestr + ".xml");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

and error is

```
{"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}
```

and the xml lines contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MeasDataCollection.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE mdc SYSTEM "MeasDataCollection.dtd">
<mdc xmlns:HTML="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml">
<mfh>
```

please help

Comment: What is this filenamestr ? Is it a file contains your xml data?

Comment: Follow the below links and get idea how to solve your problem by own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748668/data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid?noredirect=1&lq=1   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1

Answer (score 2):

You should change it

```
XDoc.LoadXml(filenamestr);
```

to

```
XDoc.Load(filenamestr);
```

`LoadXml` requires xml string instead of xml filename. You should `Load` method to load xml from file.

Comment: No, it is not true.